# Как работает генерация меню на этом сайте

Tags: javascript, html

Есть [cайт](https://zdravkamaksurova.diet/). На нём как-бы должно генерироваться фитнес меню питания. Как это реализовано - есть формы с методом отправки POST и странный javascript, который отправляет всю эту канитель на сервер, дальше я ничего не понимаю. Так же, возможно ли копирование (хотя-бы частично) той реализации, что используется на сайте?

Comment: Можно понять. Можно скопировать. Можно простить. Можно закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, т.к только что зарегестрировался на сайте. Что я могу поправить в своём вопросе, чтобы выразить его правильно - как реализована генерация файла на этом сайте и можно ли эти скрипты\хэндлеры забрать себе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, я точно вам не напишу, как они всё обрабатывают.

Но лично я делал бы это таким образом:

1. На сайте делаю что-то вроде опроса (как и в Вашем примере), где соберу информацию в массив или отдельный объект (к примеру: `{old: 17, sex: man}`).
2. Отправляю POST или GET запросом этот массив/объект на PHP файл.
3. В PHP анализирую все полученный данные условиями. К примеру:

   ```
   if( $_POST['sex'] === 'male' ){
      if( $_POST['old'] >= 10 ){
     return 'Информация 1';
      }else{
         return 'Информация 2';
      };
   }else{
      if( $_POST['old'] >= 10 ){
         return 'Информация 3';
      }else{
         return 'Информация 4';
      };
   };
   ```
4. Принимаю полученный от PHP ответ.
5. Если я сгенерировал HTML в PHP, то просто вставляю его, а если - нет, то генерирую HTML по полученным данным и вставляю

Comment: Да, думаю, что так и происходит. Всё уходит через POST. Я только не совсем понимаю вот это:
`    <script defer>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
        });
    </script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.radioAnswer input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
    var score = $(this).data('score');
    $('#questionScore').val(score);
    $('#radioQuestionForm').submit();
   });
//   $('.testBack').on('click', function() {
//    window.history.back();
//   });
  });
 </script>
`

Comment: Чёрт, как в комментах правильно выделить код?

Comment: @ПавелНасевич, это Jquery код. Что он делает: там написано, что при нажатии на `.radioAnswer input[type="radio"]`, его данные с атрибута *data-score* отправляется в *value* элемент `#questionScore` и нажимается кнопка *submit* у формы `#radioQuestionForm`

Comment: @ПавелНасевич, с помощью этого знака с двух сторон - `

Comment: спасибо, понял. А можно как-то сам хэндлер достать, чтобы посмотреть, что делается с данными из формы? Или это закрыто?

Comment: @ПавелНасевич, к сожалению, мы не сможем увидеть, что происходит в PHP, т. к. эта информация обрабатывается на сервере, куда мы не имеем доступа

Comment: Понял. Спасибо Вам большое, теперь видно немного света в конце тёмного туннеля. А формы-чекбоксы работают по тому-же принципу?

Comment: @ПавелНасевич, по идее да. Но, Вы же понимаете, каждый разработчик может вставить свои плюшки в код

Answer (score 1):

Взгляните на форму. У них там есть `input` типа `radio`. Но они его скрыли `css`ом `(display:none)`. При нажатие они `javascript`ом переправляют на `URL` с `POST` запросом.

```
<form action="https://zdravkamaksurova.diet/3" method="POST" id="radioQuestionForm">
                        <label class="radioAnswer" for="answer_0">
        <input id="answer_0" value="16" name="answer" data-score="1" type="radio">
        Почти никаква
    </label>
                        <label class="radioAnswer" for="answer_1">
        <input id="answer_1" value="17" name="answer" data-score="1.146" type="radio">
        Ходя често пеша
    </label>
                        <label class="radioAnswer" for="answer_2">
        <input id="answer_2" value="18" name="answer" data-score="1.292" type="radio">
        Тренирам 1-2 седмично
    </label>
                        <label class="radioAnswer" for="answer_3">
        <input id="answer_3" value="19" name="answer" data-score="1.438" type="radio">
        Тренирам 3-5 седмично
    </label>
                        <label class="radioAnswer" for="answer_4">
        <input id="answer_4" value="20" name="answer" data-score="1.583" type="radio">
        Тренирам 5-7 пъти седмично
    </label>
                    <input name="score" id="questionScore" value="1" type="hidden">
<input value="1" name="question" type="hidden">
<input name="_token" value="fDAU5jUw4ne7tjI6HfiwFFcphQRJpbc0SLOIFEFf" type="hidden">
<input value="radio" name="type" type="hidden">
<a href="https://zdravkamaksurova.diet/1" class="testBack">Назад</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Оу, а ведь точно. Ещё вопросик, а как работают формы-чекбоксы? (Этап 3-4-5)

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос )))). Вам надо тщательно изучать CSS3, javascript, вообщем в целом верстку веб страниц.